# Why we are using atoms in rest?

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, atom-feed

I've seen many times xml in rest web services, having the following format:

```
<author>
   <atom:link rel="author" type="application/xml" href="http://www.../author/1"/>
</author>
```

and the url (http://www.../author/1) will contain something like this:

```
<author xmlns="http://www.../ckp" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
  <name>S. Crocker</name>
  <address>None</address>
  <affiliation></affiliation>
  <email>None</email>
</author>
```

1. I was wondering why the first form of xml is being used?
2. How can these be modeled on a java model class (using the mvc pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is simple: ATOM is a solid [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) that covers a [bunch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) of [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4946) things that you want to do for publishing, updating, and otherwise managing information.

So, people use ATOM for the same reason they use HTTP - they could invest something unique, but the standard gives them better tools.

To the second, [various Java libraries exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257201/how-to-get-started-with-atom-and-java), but there is no definitive way to do this.  Everything from "write your own model objects and hand-parse the XML" through to the sort of "do it for you" libraries that question links to will work just fine.